# MP4 video slightly asynchronous - but only on initial play

Tags: flash, video, ffmpeg, h.264, mp4

Here is our procedure:

1. We create live MP4 videos using ffmpeg (H264/AAC), both as API and as command line tool.*
2. qt-faststart is used to move the metadata to the beginning of the file to enable fast playback in our Flash client.
3. Video is renamed to *.m4v.
4. User uses our Flash client to download the video and starts playing immediatly due to the metadata being at the beginning.

*Edit:*
*First, a MPG video is created with the ffmpeg API, this is then copied together with an intro and an outro video (you can simply chain MPG videos). The resulting MPG is then converted to MP4 using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i inputvideo.mpg -sameq -b 3000000 -vcodec libx264 -acodec libvo_aacenc -ac 2 -g 60 -y outputvideo.mp4
```

Basically, this does work.

The problem:

We noticed that during the initial playback (the user hasn't clicked anything yet, video still downloading or not does not make a difference), the audio is playing asychnronous, noticeable if you look out for it.

But as soon as you click around in the video (one time is enough, no matter where you click), the audio becomes more synchronous (still not perfect!) for the rest of the video.

This behaviour is the same, no matter if you view it via our Flash player or Windows Media Player. Is there anything we can do from our side (in ffmpeg or qt-faststart) to make it synchronous from the start?

Comment: Showing your ffmpeg command and complete console output may provide some useful information. Also, does this occur for both API and command-line produced videos?

Comment: Edited to show ffmpeg command. We do not log the ffmpeg console output, but we can look at it and it shows no errors (no red lines).

Comment: The output contains other useful information such as your ffmpeg version which will determine the syntax for any potential suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ha!

Turns out the problem was in the audio not being the same length as the video. As soon as that got fixed, everything was synchronous again. Should have checked that one first...
So, not really a coding bug or problem, more the fault of our content department. ;)

Comment: so your file inputvideo.mpg had longer audio than video here?

Comment: Actually, the audio was shorter than the video.